# Customize link of invitation sent by devise_invitable rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

The mail sent by devise_invitable includes invitation link like below.
`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=9gAJ9Jyf7TKk95ddUFxB`

I want to modify this link like below.
`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=9gAJ9Jyf7TKk95ddUFxB&language=en`

Does anyone know the solution method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize mailer view with your own stuff

Use this for generate devise invitable views `rails generate devise_invitable:views`
For more information about view check this [Link](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#configuring-views)

And customize `app/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instruction.html.erb` to get your stuff working.

**UPDATE**

When you invite user it will call `create` action of `Users::InvitationsController` and you can overide the controller also, refere [Customize devise invitable Controller](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#configuring-controllers)

Comment: Thanks quick response! I solved it by describing it in the file you taught as follows
`accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token, :language => 'en')`

Comment: I have another request. Could you tell me the flow until invitation_instruction.html.erb is rendered? I'd like to change 'en' in the above example to a variable. Therefore, I want to know the controller that is running before rendering this view file.

Comment: @genkiohmori I have updated the answer, let me know if you want more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I modified inherited InvitationController#create like this ->`super { |u| u.language = 'en' }`. But the @resource.language in invitation_instruction.html.erb is nil.

I followed the process with binding.pry. The @ resource used in the view file was initialized in devise / mailers / helper.rb. But here I am in library so I do not want to edit it.

Also, in inherited invitations_controller.rb I defined an instance variable @ lang different from @ resrouce and assigned "en", but I could not refer to @ lang in the view file.

Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: Actually, I dont have idea about internationalisation, so I cant suggest any better way. :)

Comment: Finally I realized it. The function to override was invite_resource, not create. After overriding the invite_resource, I could assign the language property to the @ resource of the view file. Thank you for your cooperation!!

Comment: Yes, you are right if you are inviting user using this path `new_user_invitation_path` it will call accordingly new and create action of invitation controller, but if you are inviting user via `User.invite(email)` it will call `invite_user` function.
So you have to overide respected way, to get your stuff working.